# Can hydrogen peroxide be considered an alkali?

Tags: acid-base

Hydrogen peroxide is miscible with water, can neutralize acids, and produces H2O, but I've never seen it labeled as an alkali, could we still consider hydrogen peroxide an alkali?

Comment: No, and it doesn't neutralize acids. Even if it did it wouldn't be enough. And what gave you such idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly, H2O2 has been considered an acid because its dissociation constant is smaller than that of H2O:

"The available literature indicate that hydrogen peroxide is a weak inorganic acid with a dissociation constant between 2.24 and 2.4E-12 at 25 °C, which corresponds to a value for pKa ranging from 11.62 to 11.65.
Hydrogen peroxide - Registration Dossier - ECHA
echa.europa.eu/registration-dossier/-/registered-dossier/15701/4/22"

However, it would hardly be useful in neutralizing an alkali, but strong bases would generate OOH- ions.